# Delphi 7 Bitmap. SaveToFile and Transparent

Tags: delphi, icons, transparency

I want to save an ico from db to file, but I have a problem with transparency.
When I save it to c:\1.ico, the result file does have no transparency.

```
procedure DBIconsToFIle;
var
  Streams: TStream;
  fIcon : TBitmap;
begin
  //load stream from db
  FIcon.LoadFromStream(Streams);
  FIcon := TBitmap.Create;
  FIcon.TransparentColor := clWhite;
  FIcon.PixelFormat := pf32bit;
  FIcon.Height := 16;
  FIcon.Width := 16;
  FIcon.SaveToFile(tmpFile);
  //destroys
end;
```

How I can save it with transparency?

Comment: The filename extension for icons is .ico, not .icon.

Comment: Also, why don't you use `TIcon` instead of `TBitmap` if you want to save an icon?

Comment: And why in the world do you use `LoadFromStream` first and `TBitmap.Create` second?!

Comment: I've corrected the 'icon'-'ico' problem.

Comment: also 32bpp bitmaps use alpha transparency

Comment: sorry, it's wans in my real code.

Comment: .ico - true and constructor going first

Comment: @TheHorse: Please post real code. Making up code and asking why it doesn't work won't help you solve your problem, and it wastes our time looking to find things that aren't really the issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The filename extension for icons is .ico, not .icon. Also, why don't you use `TIcon` instead of `TBitmap` if you want to save an icon? And why in the world do you use `LoadFromStream` first and `TBitmap.Create` second?!

Does the slightly more normal code

```
var
  Icon: TIcon;
begin
  Icon := TIcon.Create;
  try
    Icon.LoadFromStream(SomeStream);
    Icon.SaveToFile(SomeFileName);
  finally
    Icon.Free;
  end;
```

work for you?

Comment: Now you have learned that Bitmap is not an Icon, even if you call the variable name Icon.  :-)